# How to cast object of class id to CGPoint for NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, class, casting, cgpoint

If I have an object myObject of class id, how would I "cast" it as a CGPoint (given that I have performed introspection and know myObject to a CGPoint)? This is despite the fact that CGPoint is not a real Obj-C class.

Simply doing `(CGPoint)myObject` returns the following error:

`Used type 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') where arithmetic or pointer type is required`

I want to do this so that I can check if the object being passed to an NSMutableArray is a CGPoint, and if it is, to wrap the CGPoint in an NSValue automatically; e.g.:

```
- (void)addObjectToNewMutableArray:(id)object
{
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    id objectToAdd = object;
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[CGPoint class]]) // pseudo-code, doesn't work
    {
        objectToAdd = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:object];
    }
    [myArray addObject:objectToAdd];
    return myArray;
}
```

**ADDITIONAL CODE**

Here are the functions I use to perform "introspection":

```
+ (BOOL)validateObject:(id)object
{
    if (object)
    {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]])
        {
            NSValue *value = (NSValue *)object;
            if (CGPointEqualToPoint([value CGPointValue], [value CGPointValue]))
            {
                return YES;
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"[TEST] Invalid object: object is not CGPoint");
                return NO;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"[TEST] Invalid object: class not allowed (%@)", [object class]);
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

+ (BOOL)validateArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    for (id object in array)
    {
        if (object)
        {
            if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]])
            {
                NSValue *value = (NSValue *)object;
                if (!(CGPointEqualToPoint([value CGPointValue], [value CGPointValue])))
                {
                    NSLog(@"[TEST] Invalid object: object is not CGPoint");
                    return NO;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"[TEST] Invalid object: class not allowed (%@)", [object class]);
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

+ (NSValue *)convertObject:(CGPoint)object
{
    return [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:object];
}
```

Comment: `CGPoint` is not an Objective-C object type.  What introspection did you do?  Edit your post to show us your introspection code and its output.

Comment: CGPoint isn't a class. Your `id` can't be a CGPoint object. It's impossible. It might be a CGPoint wrapped in an NSValue though. Log `[myObject class]`. What do you get?

Comment: Okay I'll rewrite my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `CGPoint` is not an Objective-C object.  You cannot pass one to your `addObjectToNewMutableArray:` method.  The compiler will not let you.

You need to wrap the `CGPoint` in an `NSValue` and pass that wrapper to your `addObjectToNewMutableArray:` method.

If you have an `NSValue` and you want to test whether it contains a `CGPoint`, you can ask it like this:

```
if (strcmp([value objCType], @encode(CGPoint)) == 0) {
    CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Previously I had made a custom CGPointsArray class wherein I could add and extract CGPoints to a mutable array without an NSValue wrapper, but now that I am more familiar with Obj-C I see that it is more of a burden than a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

a point isnt an object and therefore cant be cast to one...
or vice-versa

casting doesnt transform data it only changes how data is interpreted!

id is basically short for NSObject* btw

Comment: `id` is not “short for” `NSObject*`.  There are other root classes besides `NSObject`, like `NSProxy`.

Comment: I am aware and I said basically because I simplified it.. its actually  typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id or something .. my point was that it is an OBJECT;